# Coordinates of a quadrilateral given 2 adjacent corners, directions from each corner to their other adjacent corner, and the area

Tags: geometry, area

I am making a game, and an interesting math problem has arisen that has stumped me (problem description is this post's title). Below is the link to the picture of the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried using the method for finding the area of irregular polygons, but the resulting equation is too complex for me to isolate the necessary variable.

Thanks for your time!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHVXz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \frac{P_2 - P_1}{\|P_2 - P_1\|}$, and $v = u^{\perp} = (-u_y, u_x)$. We'll do everything in terms of $u$ and $v$, which we'll regard as vectors along the coordinate axes of a new coordinate system.

Let 
$$
w_1 = \frac{ P_3 - P_1 }{\| P_3 - P_1 \|} 
$$
and 
$$
w_2 = \frac{ P_4 - P_2 }{\| P_4 - P_2 \|} 
$$
These are unit vectors along each of the "new" edges. And let 
$$
y_i = w_i \cdot v.
$$

Your points $P_5$ and $P_6$ are going to have the form 
$$
P_5 = P_1 + \frac{t}{y_1} w_1 \\
P_6 = P_2 + \frac{t}{y_2} w_2
$$
so that distance from $P_5$ to $P_1$ perpendicular to the $P_1P_2$ line, which is the projection of the $P_5 - P_1$ onto $v$, is the same as the corresponding distance from $P_2$ to $P_6$.

The only question is "What is $t$?"

Well, the area of the polygon, for a given $t$, is simply the product of the "height" (distance perpendicular to $P_1P_2$) and the width, which is the average of the length of the edge $P_1P_2$ and the edge $P_5P_6$. Let's write that out:

The height is 
\begin{align}
H &= v \cdot (P_5 - P_1)\\
 &= v \cdot \frac{t}{y_1} w_1\\
 &= \frac{t}{y_1} v \cdot w_1\\
\end{align}
The width of the base is $\| P_2 - P_1 \| = u \cdot (P_2 - P_1)$.

The width of the top edge is 
\begin{align}
\| P_6 - P_5 \| 
 &= u \cdot (P_6 - P_5)\\
 &= u \cdot (P_2 - P_1) + t ~u \cdot (\frac{w_2}{y_2} - \frac{w_1}{y_1})
\end{align}
The average of these is 
$$
W = u \cdot (P_2 - P_1) + \frac{t}{2} ~u \cdot (\frac{w_2}{y_2} - \frac{w_1}{y_1}).
$$
You want the product of $H$ and $W$ to be $A$, i.e. 
$$
A =  (\frac{t}{y_1} v \cdot w_1) \cdot (u \cdot (P_2 - P_1) + \frac{t}{2} ~u \cdot (\frac{w_2}{y_2} - \frac{w_1}{y_1})).
$$

Letting $s_1 = \frac{w_1}{y_1}$ and $s_2 = \frac{w_2}{y_2}$, this becomes

\begin{align}
A &=  (t v \cdot s_1) \cdot (u \cdot (P_2 - P_1) + \frac{t}{2} u \cdot (s_2 - s_1)).
\end{align}

Now $u \cdot (P_2 - P_1)$ is simply $\| P_2 - P_1 \|$, so this all becomes
\begin{align}
A &=  (t v \cdot s_1) \cdot (\|P_2 - P_1\| + t u \cdot \frac{s_2 - s_1}{2}).
\end{align}
Let's simplify once more, by letting 
$$
R = v \cdot s_1 \\
S = u \cdot \frac{s_2 - s_1}{2}\\
L = \|P_2 - P_1 \|.
$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
A 
&=  (t R) \cdot (L + t S)\\
&=  t RL + t^2 RS\\
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
0 &= t^2 RS +  t RL - A
\end{align}
which is a quadratic in $t$, hence 
\begin{align}
t &= \frac{-RL \pm \sqrt{(RL)^2 + 4 A RS}}{2RS}
\end{align}
You almost certainly want $t$ positive, so that means you want to choose the "+" instead of the "-". And that gives you your answer.